# how to disable delete action in laravel encore admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-admin

Please see the attached image. I want to disable or remove delete action in laravel encore admin.[image: Please see hilighted area in image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use actions method to disable grid actions.

```
$grid->actions(function ($actions) {
    $actions->disableDelete();
    $actions->disableEdit();
});
```